# Programmatically Load SkyDrive Workbook with Embedded Excel Web App

Tags: excel, onedrive

My use case is a web page which allows users to load an Excel file stored on SkyDrive, whose format I do not control, and have the user select a range of cells from that file to send their data to a web service.  I would like to embed an Excel Web App in my web page for this purpose and use the Ewa library to interact with the cells.  In order to do this I need to programmatically load an arbitrary workbook from SkyDrive that I don't know ahead of time.  This means that I can't just use the manual Javascript Embed menu option in SkyDrive which provides the fileToken.  Can I pull an Excel Web App fileToken from SkyDrive programmatically?